# How to find out allowed memory for a specific Drupal page

Tags: debugging

I want to find out how much allowed memory a page uses after it is loaded on my drupal 6 site. I know that you can do this when a page is not loading correctly, by enabling errors in php.ini. How do find this out on successful page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [performance module](http://drupal.org/project/performance) (formerly part of [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)):

> This module provides performance statistics logging for a site, such as page generation times, and **memory usage, for each page load**.
>
> This module is useful for developers and site administrators alike to identify pages that are slow to generate or use excessive memory.

emphasis mine.

Comment: Can summary logging be viewed without having to install the memcache module and modifying setting.php?

Comment: On the module page, 2 options down from the one you're talking about, it says "Support for normal page cache.". I would assume so :) Also _"Only summary logging with Memcache, APC or similar mechanisms are the recommended mode for live sites, with a threshold of 2 or more."_ So yes it's available, but it's not recommended to use anything other than an advanced cache solution on a production site

Comment: How about turning normal page caching on when I want to know the allowed memory but turning it off when I'm not using it?

Comment: @Emanegux I'm not sure; I use memcache even on dev (try to replicate live environment as much as possible). Best thing would be to install it and see what mileage you get out of it

Comment: I gave it a shot on my production site and it tells me exactly what I want to know but the updates were happening so fast I can't even imagine what was going on in the database table. I disabled the module now that I no longer need it. I guess I'll just reenable the module when I need to know the memory and disable it when I don't.